# Images not loading when browsing in IIS 10

Tags: javascript, css, iis-10

I am trying to create a slide show with images published from excel. The images work just fine when opening straight from the file. The images do not work when navigating to http://localhost nor browsing from IIS settings. Please see the code below. I have been at this for hours now and cant seem to find a fix.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>SHL Dashboard</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="35;url=default.html">
<style>
/* Change body background-color to change fade out color. */
body.siteshow { margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#FFFFFF; }
#menu
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:9pt;
    display:none;
    opacity:0.00;
    -mozopacity:0.00;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    border:3px dotted #999999;
}
#menu a { color:#ffffff; }
#menu a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
#title { font-size:11pt; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:2; }
#slides { font-size:9pt; line-height:16pt; }
.button { width:60px; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:1; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var current_idx = 0;
var slides = new Array();
var menuwin;
var show_timer;
var menu_timer;
var menu;
var content;
var loaded = true;
// Define your "slides". 3 values for each are:
//      1. Duration in seconds.
//      2. Title to be used in menu.
//      3. Source URL. Can be full URI or a relative URL.
slides[1] = new Array(5, "Announcement 1", "C:/Website/shldash.com/wwwroot/Announcement_1.htm");
slides[2] = new Array(5, "Announcement 2", "C:/Website/shldash.com/wwwroot/Announcement_2.htm");
slides[3] = new Array(5, "Announcement 3", "C:/Website/shldash.com/wwwroot/Announcement_3.htm");
slides[4] = new Array(5, "Announcement 4", "C:/Website/shldash.com/wwwroot/Announcement_4.htm");
slides[5] = new Array(5, "Cust and Vis info", "C:/Website/shldash.com/wwwroot/Cust%20and%20Vis%20Info.htm");
slides[6] = new Array(5, "SHL Logo", "C:/Website/shldash.com/wwwroot/Dash_Logo.htm");
slides[7] = new Array(5, "Job info", "C:/Website/shldash.com/wwwroot/Job%20Openings.htm");
function xMenuInit()
{
    var html = "";
    for(idx=1; idx<slides.length; idx++) {
        html += '<a href="javascript:Navigate('+idx+')">' +
            slides[idx][1] + "</a><br />\n";
    }
    document.getElementById("slides").innerHTML = html;
    menu.style.display = "block";
}
function xMenuShow()
{
    clearTimeout(menu_timer);
    opacity('menu', 0, 90, 500);
    menu_timer = setTimeout("MenuHide()", 3500);
}
function MenuHide()
{
    opacity('menu', 90, 0, 500);
}
function Pause()
{
    clearTimeout(show_timer);
    document.getElementById('play').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('pause').style.display = "none";
}
function Navigate(slide_idx)
{
    clearTimeout(show_timer);
    if (current_idx == 0) {
        if (!slide_idx) { slide_idx = 1; }
        current_idx = slide_idx;
        content.src = slides[current_idx][2];
        document.getElementById('play').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('pause').style.display = "block";
        show_timer = setTimeout("Navigate()", slides[current_idx][0]*1000);
        return;
    }
    if (slide_idx) {
        current_idx = slide_idx;
        content.src = slides[current_idx][2];
        document.getElementById('play').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('pause').style.display = "none";
        return;
    }
    loaded = false;
    current_idx++;
    if ( current_idx == slides.length) { current_idx = 1; }
    opacity('content', 100, 0, 500);
    document.getElementById('play').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('pause').style.display = "block";
    show_timer = setTimeout("Navigate()", slides[current_idx][0]*1000);
    return;   
}
function opacity(id, opacStart, opacEnd, millisec)
{
    //speed for each frame
    var speed = Math.round(millisec / 100);
    var timer = 0;
    //determine the direction for the blending, if start and end are the same nothing happens
    if(opacStart > opacEnd) {
        for(i = opacStart; i >= opacEnd; i--) {
            setTimeout("changeOpac(" + i + ",'" + id + "')",(timer * speed));
            timer++;
        }
        if (opacEnd == 0) { setTimeout("FadeOutTrigger('"+id+"')",((timer-1) * speed));; }
        //if (opacEnd == 0) { FadeOutTrigger(id); }
    } else if(opacStart < opacEnd) {
        if (opacStart == 0) { FadeInTrigger(id); }
        for(i = opacStart; i <= opacEnd; i++)
            {
            setTimeout("changeOpac(" + i + ",'" + id + "')",(timer * speed));
            timer++;
        }
    }
}
//change the opacity for different browsers
function changeOpac(opacity, id)
{
    var object = document.getElementById(id).style;
    object.opacity = (opacity / 100);
    object.MozOpacity = (opacity / 100);
    object.KhtmlOpacity = (opacity / 100);
    object.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + opacity + ")";
}
function FadeOutTrigger(id)
{
    //alert('FadeOut: '+id);
    switch(id) {
    case "menu":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
        break;
    case "content":
        content.src = slides[current_idx][2];
        //setTimeout("opacity('content', 0, 100, 500)", 1000);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
function FadeInTrigger(id)
{
    //alert('FadeIn: '+id);
    switch(id) {
    case "menu":
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        break;
    case "content":
        //opacity('content', 0, 100, 500);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
function FadeInContent()
{
    if (!loaded) {
        opacity('content', 0, 100, 500);
        loaded = true;
    }
}
function LoadTrigger()
{
    //self.resizeTo(1366,768);
    menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    content = document.getElementById('content');
    Navigate();
    MenuInit();
    MenuShow();
}
window.onload = LoadTrigger;
</script>
</head>
<body class="siteshow">
<iframe id="content" name="content" style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="no" scrolling="auto" src="" onmouseover="MenuShow();" onload="FadeInContent();" ></iframe>
<div id="menu">
    <div id="title">SiteShow Menu</div>
    <div id="slides">
    </div>
    <p>
        <input id="pause" class="button" style="display:block;" type="button" value="pause" onclick="Pause()" />
        <input id="play" class="button" style="display:none;" type="button" value="play" onclick="Navigate()" />
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A snippet makes only sense with executable code (which is not the case here) and a [mcve] with the focus on _minimal_. The snippet editor has distinct places for Markup/HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

Comment: Arrays in JavaScript begin at index `0`. Don't use strings as the first parameter of `setTimeout`/`setInterval`.

Comment: Change `C:/Website/shldash.com/wwwroot/Announcement_1.htm` to `Announcement_1.htm`, and the like, or `content.src = slides[current_idx][2];` will have the incorrect path. Of course, I'm assuming that `Announcement_1.htm` is in your root folder, maybe `htdocs`.

Comment: Stackslave, this fixed the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A webpage has no access to your local filesystem. Don't use absolute URLs, use root-relative URLs.

That's how your `slides` should probably look like. btw. Arrays in JS start with the index `0` not `1`.

```js
var slides = [
    [5, "Announcement 1", "/Announcement_1.htm"],
    [5, "Announcement 2", "/Announcement_2.htm"],
    [5, "Announcement 3", "/Announcement_3.htm"],
    [5, "Announcement 4", "/Announcement_4.htm"],
    [5, "Cust and Vis info", "/Cust%20and%20Vis%20Info.htm"],
    [5, "SHL Logo", "/Dash_Logo.htm"],
    [5, "Job info", "/Job%20Openings.htm"]
];
```

---

Then, please declare the variables that you use `for(let idx=0; ...`.

---

don't use `setTimeout("MenuHide()", 3500);` with strings. They need to be eval'd and eval is evil. Pass a function: `setTimeout(MenuHide, 3500);`

---

`KhtmlOpacity` and `filter = "alpha(opacity=...`? How far downwards compatable do you want to stay? These were used for Safari 1.x and IE 5-9.